SSH Connection Lost Error on DigitalOcean Droplet Console
I'm experiencing an issue with accessing my DigitalOcean Droplet. When I attempt to connect using the Droplet Console in the DigitalOcean Control Panel, I receive a "SSH connection lost" error. Here are the details:
Problem:
**Error Message: **SSH connection lost
Action Taken: Clicked on the "Launch Droplet Console" button in the DigitalOcean Control Panel
Droplet Status: The Droplet is running but unresponsive to SSH commands.
SSH Configuration: I have not changed the default SSH configuration settings.
Steps Taken:

Tried accessing the Droplet Console multiple times.
Verified that the Droplet is running and that there are no network issues from my end.
Checked DigitalOcean documentation for troubleshooting SSH connection issues.

Additional Information:

Droplet Console Access: I can access the Droplet Console but get the SSH connection lost error upon login attempt.

Questions:

What could be causing the "SSH connection lost" error in the DigitalOcean Droplet Console?
How can I resolve this issue to regain access to my Droplet?
Are there any additional steps I should take to troubleshoot or recover the Droplet?


Here are couple of links that may be helpful:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/how-to-troubleshoot-ssh-connectivity-issues/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/getting-ssh-connection-lost

Ask your vendor?
